# Chartjs 2.0 - Increase height of x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/xukuhanota/1/edit?output

I'm trying to increase the height (or essentially, the top/bottom padding) of the labels (ticks?) along the x axis.

Here is the relevant bit of code for the chart:

```
xAxes: [{
  id: 'x-axis-0',
  type: 'category',

  gridLines: {
    display: false,
  },

  ticks: {
    fontSize: 16,
    maxRotation: 0,
    fontFamily: "opensans",
    fontStyle: "bold",

    paddingTop: 10,         // doesnt work 
    paddingBottom: 10,      // doesnt work 
  },


  paddingTop: 10,           // doesnt work 
  paddingBottom: 10,        // doesnt work
```

According to [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-category-scale), there are `paddingBottom` and `paddingTop` properties, but I don't know if/how they apply to the ticks vs scales.

Answer (score 9):

Just for completeness, provide a options Object like this and your axis will have a fixed height, or change some padding values

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            afterFit: (scale) => {
                scale.height = 120;
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display:false,
        afterFit: (scale) => {
            scale.height = 40;
        }
    }]
},

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says "Scale instances are given the following properties". To me it does not sound like this is some setting you can give, but rather some setting you can expect if you implement your own scale.

I had a brief look at the [code for their scale implementation](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/fbecfa2baf81cd009896ebbca4a225d95dd83084/src/core/core.scale.js), and it looks like you don't have much direct control on the computation of the padding properties, except one setting `padding` that is not documented (see line 40 in the linked version). I tried applying it in your jsbin (just add a `padding` property to the `ticks` object): it did have an effect on the Y axis, but not the X one.

It looks like you will need to provide your own scale implementation if you want better control... In the version I linked, the padding is computed mostly in the [`calculateTickRotation`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/fbecfa2baf81cd009896ebbca4a225d95dd83084/src/core/core.scale.js#L187) and [`fit`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/fbecfa2baf81cd009896ebbca4a225d95dd83084/src/core/core.scale.js#L266) methods. So changing the padding might be as easy as giving [an afterFit callback](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration) to the scale options, in which you simply change the `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`. I haven't tried. Otherwise, [create a subclass of Scale](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-scale-types) and provide an afterFit method.

I'm not chart.js expert, so don't take this as a complete and definitive answer, but I hope this gives a useful direction.

Comment: Thanks. I'm comfortable editing the source if you see the line it's computed on... Having trouble finding even that.

Comment: Could be easier than I thought after a second look, check my updated answer.

Comment: I'm hooked into the `afterFit` callback on xAxes, and seeing the scale instance as the parameter. I can then edit `scale.paddingTop = 10` for example but nothing seems to be changed. Am I to return a value? Here is an updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/neyiyuviku/1/edit

Comment: Here's the [category scale](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/scales/scale.category.js), I suspect I can make modifications to this?